# WPF - помощь с выбором контрола

Tags: wpf, controls

уважаемые! У меня несколько общий вопрос.

Нужно реализовать: строку (я не сказал, что это должно быть TextBox) для ввода улицы так, чтобы по вводимому значению автоматически определялось множество вариантов адресов с такой улицей (сочетание "область - город - улица, которая начинается на введенные символы"), оперативно показывалась в качестве списка-подсказки к этой строке, и пользователь мог мышкой или стрелками выбрать подходящий вариант. Короче, поведение как у IntelliSence, только для адресов.

Я уже реализовать весь "back-end" (сделал во VM метод, который выдает массив подсказок по введенному префиксу слова). Дело за малым... я не знаю, каким лучше воспользоваться контролом и какими его свойствами. Желательно, если есть такая возможность, это прикрутить к редактируемому ComboBox.

Благодарю за советы и/или примеры :)

Comment: Так в чем проблема использовать ComboBox, в который можно писать текст?

Comment: У меня и был на улицу ComboBox. Туда складывался список улиц для объекта (города) предыдущего уровня. Теперь концепция поменялась. Пользователь не хочет каскадом выбирать Область - Город - Улица. Он хочет начать вводить улицу, и чтобы ему показали варианты адресов с такой улицей, но при этом старая возможность выбрать каскадом сохранилась. Поэтому проблема в том, что именно у ComboBox я не хочу трогать ItemsSource, а свойство ToolTip (насколько я знаю) не позволяет выбирать значение - только подсказывает. Или позволяет?

Comment: Привяжите к ComboBox коллекцию (`ObservableCollection`) с улицами и по мере ввода просто сортируйте ее в нужном порядке, например, чтобы наиболее подходящие элементы были вверху (хотя я бы сделал, чтобы элементы фильтровались и неподходящие просто исчезали из списка)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все удачно собрал на ComboBox.

В итоге, я создал два класса - один для элемента дерева, содержащего элемент адреса, а другой - подсказка, содержащая информацию по полному адресу, начинающемуся с введенного текста. Оба класса связаны одним интерфейсом.

ItemsSource у ComboBox - List, где Т - мой интерфейс. Это позволило мне оперативно подменять разнородные ItemsSource'ы у ComboBox'а.

ComboBox открыл для редактирования (IsEditable=true). Подписался на события TextChanged и SelectionChanged.

По событию TextChanged на лету получаю список подсказок, подменяю ItemsSource на них - пользователь видит подсказки. По событию SelectionChanged заполняю все вышестоящие ComboBox'ы, включая ComboBox с подсказками, из выбранной подсказки, опять оперативно подменяя ItemsSource.